# Change in display languages to Turkish results in "80070002" errors in COM Interop

Tags: windows, vb6, localization, windows-installer

I'm utterly stumped, so what I'm looking for is a body of speculation. Or maybe someone actually knows what's going on.

I have a program written in VB6 which has had every user interface element font set to "MS Sans Serif, 7 point", in an effort to create an English/Turkish localization. The localized strings are compiled into the VB6 EXE, and there is custom code to do the hot-switching between languages.

The program reaches through COM to a .NET DLL assembly which carries a "tr" satellite assembly with it, so that is also in the mix.

With a clean test system set with the display language (NOT the non-unicode setting, the other, more general one) to "English" the software runs without problems.

When it is set to Turkish, the .NET Interop system returns "Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)' -- Automation error -- The system cannot find the file specified." as soon as (it appears) the .NET DLL is called. (EDIT: This may not be the .NET DLL. I've opened an incident with Microsoft for more information from a deep trace.)

Because this is a clean-system test, there were no diagnostic tools installed, but a trace with Sysinternals ProcMon failed to show me something I could recognize.

The question becomes: Is that the right tool to go tracing my obscure little "file not found" error? Are there better tools? What should I be looking for?

But most fundamentally, does anyone know what changes when the display language changes, that would cause either a VB6 EXE or an Interop DLL to fail?

(EDIT) -- I have now tested this with five different display languages; only Turkish is failing.

Comment: It is a Windows error, "File not found".  ProcMon certainly should show you the program searching for the file.  Fwiw, given that this is a COM server, .NET will have very low odds finding the satellite assembly.

Comment: Hans, I don't think this is a failed satellite assembly problem; the default behavior in those cases is to fall back on embedded resources. Instead I'm getting file not found errors.

Comment: On a french VB6 compiled program, a VB6FR.DLL is required. Maybe it's the same kind of issue with turkish. As Hans said, procmon should help there whether that's a .NET or COM issue.

Comment: Procmon is in use, but there are several thousand entries from that error moment and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot account for the source of this error. Instead, after removing an "AMUS" directive from the installer, the error no longer occurs after installation. According to Microsoft's summary of the problem after I did some testing and couldn't reproduce it any longer:

> The theory is there was something wrong with your install package (MSI
>   packaged using InstallShield).  You were using the “REINSTALL=AMUS”
>   install setting which is a dangerous setting because it allows for
>   ‘file downgrades’. Newer files can be overwritten with older versions.
>   Likely there was a overwritten file with the wrong version and it
>   failed to load because the dependency was for a newer version.

So... I'm gonna mark this one as answered with this answer, and add a Windows Installer key to the question. Steer clear of "AMUS" when calling Windows Installer...

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have an I (i) in there!

I don't know how you are loading your DLLs, or if you've changed just the UI Thread or the worker threads' culture to Turkish, so I might be off a little, BUT...

Double check any file loads, any paths, and strings of importance etc. If they have an i, I in them, and you are using case operations (to lower, to upper) it will all go wrong with Turkish language.

We had a similar issue with our .net app and it's a pain to fix and go round using a specific culture for some things, but you can't trust to upper or to lower and the turkish language!

good luck.

Comment: The DLL has a lot of COM Interop references. Naturally, all these stub DLL's start with the word "Interop" by convention. Could that be it?

Comment: It depends how these are being loaded, it it your own code? Try and output the 'path' of the dll/interop you are trying to load just before you actually load it. Also, try setting your main threads culture to en-GB, to ensure your main thread is not turkish, but your UI thread can be turkish.

Comment: All of the DLL/Interop loading is taking place with whatever mscoree does automatically. It occurs to me that this might be a pure VB6 problem since there is one successful call into the .NET component before the error occurs, and it occurs before the form is fully displayed, perhaps during painting.